# Standalone FlashBuilder 4.6 as HTML 5 IDE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I know that with Eclipse I can get plugins to do HTML 5 development but can I do it with standalone FlashBuilder 4.6?

I tried by downloading JSDT and I got errors.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you got?

Comment: Can't say about standalone FB 4.6, but there are several other options  available for html 5 development like : Adobe Edge code, aptana studio, Eclipse with plugins and many more. you can try them.

Comment: Thanks Vipul, I'm aware of those. I'm just trying to have one IDE for all my development but without JSDT I just don't think I can do it.

Comment: @duTr: The message is that I'm some JSDT core bundle: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JSDT jQuery Integration 1.6.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery_feature.feature.group 1.6.0)
  Missing requirement: JSDT jQuery API 1.6.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery.api 1.6.0) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [1.1.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JSDT jQuery Integration 1.6.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery_feature.feature.group 1.6.0)
    To: org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery.api [1.6.0]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it done with FlashBuilder 4.6 so I downloaded latest version of Eclipse and installed Google Webkit to do HTML5 development.